# Allow Contributor to edit their own posts after Adm aproval

Tags: functions, user-roles

Contributors loses the ability to edit their posts after one admin approves their post.

I'd like to know how can I add the capability of them to edit their posts, even after admin approval or admin edit. I don't want to use any plugin for that..

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a the `edit_published_posts` capability for the `contributor` role in the `functions.php`

```
add_filter('init', function () {
    $role = get_role('contributor');
    $role->add_cap('edit_published_posts');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Author role provides this functionality by default.
Else you can use any user role editor plugin to customize capabilities